# Populate text field with variable and show text

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

Here's my code:

```
set todayDate to do shell script "date '+%Y/%m/%d'"

set salesRef to "COMPANY-AB" & "-" & theCustomerInitials & "-" & todayDate & "-" & theCustomerID

set the clipboard to salesRef as text
    display dialog salesRef as text buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

Here's the UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRttb.png

I'd like to make the text 'Copied!' appear when the successfully completes the clipboard line, but remain hidden until then, and also populate the text field at the bottom with the 'salesRef' variable, so the user get's an output.

Essentially then, I'll be able to remove the display dialog. But I can't work out how to do this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successfully managed this by adding these lines:

```
property theTextField : missing value
```

…

```
theTextField's setStringValue:salesRef
```

Then created a connection to the text field in IB by control dragging from the App Delegate to the text field, and selecting the property.

Answer (score 0):

## Are you ok with `NSAppleScript`?

if so here is an example:

```
    NSAppleScript *myScriptThatShouldGimmeStuff = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
    @"return (text returned of (display dialog \"gimme your input:\" default answer \"\" buttons {\"Ok\"} default button 1))"];
    //this previous line is the applescript
    
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *theStuff = [myScriptThatShouldGimmeStuff executeAndReturnError:nil];
    self.myTextBoxToPutInputIn.stringValue = [theStuff stringValue]; //[theStuff stringValue] is the result returned
              
             /|\
            / | \ 
           /  |  \ 
              |   
              |
//don't forget to change this
//(I didn't comment out the arrow because i want xcode
// to throw you an error so you don't forget to change that).
```

Comment: Sweet arrow, dude.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

So it is not clear from you code what you are doing, but IF you are using ASOC, then you have to define OUTLETS to the controls in your UI, and then you just set the .stringValue of the outlet to whatever string you want to appear in them.

If you don't know how to set up outlets, watch this video and download the example code (look for INTRO VIDEO on the page):
http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/develop/index.html

Or for another step-by-step example, here:
http://asobjcresources.weebly.com/getting-a-text-field-input.html